# PHP Foursquare API returns Null to venues/search

Tags: php, mysql, foursquare

I'm trying to export categories from the foursquare using a knowledge (lat, long) `MySQL` database record on my disc.

When I request to foursquare I receive only NULL and not the data expected for.

Follow the code:

```
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $total = $resultA["place"];
        $lat = addslashes($resultA["place_lat"]);
        $lng = addslashes($resultA["place_lng"]);
        $name = addslashes($resultA["place_name"]);

            $client_key = 'client_id';
            $client_secret = 'client_secret';

            $curlhandle = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
                            ?client_id=client_id
                            &client_secret=client_secret
                            &v=20141006
                            &ll=$lat,$lng");
            curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            **$response = curl_exec($curlhandle)**;
            curl_close($curlhandle);
            $venues = json_decode($response);
```

Besides this problem when I run the code on my broswer I have the problem: "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\recomendacao\analisarUser.php on line `**$response = curl_exec($curlhandle)**`"

Someone knows what could case it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your curl is too slow to execute the code.

Try to maximize the execution time of curl to and put 
this at the beginning of your script.

```
  // if you set it to 0 , it mean the limit to
  // infinite, maximum available limit.
    ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 0);

   //Or give it a limit on your wish
   ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 500);
```

Hope that may help you

You can further try to add try catch block to your  code in order throw exception.

```
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$total = $resultA["place"];
$lat = addslashes($resultA["place_lat"]);
$lng = addslashes($resultA["place_lng"]);
$name = addslashes($resultA["place_name"]);

$client_key = 'client_id';
$client_secret = 'client_secret';

try {


        $client_key = 'client_id';
        $client_secret = 'client_secret';

        $curlhandle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
                        ?client_id=client_id
                        &client_secret=client_secret
                        &v=20141006
                        &ll=$lat,$lng");
        curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
    if($response !== FALSE):
    curl_close($curlhandle);
    $venues = json_decode($response);
    endif;

}
catch(Exception $ex){
    throw new Exception("Invalid URL",0,$ex);
}
```

Comment: Mubo,
The booth limit helped to prolong the excection time, but the Fatal error still happens.
The most stranger to me is, if I degud the code the variable $response is always 0, therefor this is not what I'm expecting for.
Could you help again, please?